# Can I make the wishlist reusable?

Tags: wishlist

Is there a way to make the wishlist items stay there? So when the customer adds it to the cart they still remain in the wishlist.  I also want it to be saved with the login and not by a local cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will involve some custom coding if you want to do this. A good explanation of this is in here http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.nl/2012/02/keep-products-in-wishlist-after-adding.html

Hope this helps